# Ext JS regex and getcmp

Tags: extjs, grid, matcher

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid');

var matcher = new RegExp(Ext.String.escapeRegex(newValue), "i");
```

Is there someone who can explain these lines of code to me?

Comment: Check out the ExtJS' [API](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.html#method-getCmp) [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.String.html#method-escapeRegex) and Mozilla's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.getCmp` is sort of a `document.getElementById()` of ExtJS.

You create an element like:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    title: 'Foo',
    html: 'Bar',
    id: 'mytest',
    renderTo: document.body
 });
```

then running `Ext.getCmp('mytest')` will return that panel instance so you can do things to it, for example:

```
var panel = Ext.getCmp('mytest');
test.setTitle('Hello');
```

Creating a new RegExp has nothing to do with ExtJS, it's Javascript's standard way (one of) to create regular expressions (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

`Ext.String.escapeRegex` will format a string in a way that is valid to be used in Regular expressions so `Ext.String.escapeRegex(abs-$dxjksgg)` will return `abs\-\$dxjksgg`

Comment: No problem, note that setting ids and using Ext.getCmp() is not the best alternative. Try to use `Ext.ComponenQuery.query()` so you can grab your component using selectors (like CSS selectors).

Comment: It was actually a code   onTextFieldChange: function(field, newValue, oldValue, options){
        var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid');
        grid.store.clearFilter();

        if (newValue) {
            var matcher = new RegExp(Ext.String.escapeRegex(newValue), "i");
            grid.store.filter({
                filterFn: function(record) {
                    return matcher.test(record.get('kod')) ||
                        matcher.test(record.get('unvan')) ;
                }
            });
        }
    }

Comment: live find(search) in grid